# Need explanation how we simplified expression for variance

Tags: statistics

I cannot really understand how we did simplification for our variance. Like how we got E[X^2] on the second line. Probably some algebra gaps.. but I cannot really make sense of it. Need help! Thank you.

$$\begin{align}
& = \sum_xx^2p(x) - 2\mu\sum_xxp(x)+\mu^2\sum_xp(x) \\
& = E[X^2] - 2\mu^2+\mu \\
&= E[X^2] - \mu^2
\end{align}$$

... how then from this we got

$$Var(X) = E[X^2] - E([X])^2$$

Comment: I think it is more than some algebra, do you know why $E[X] = \sum_x xp(x)?$ Or have you seen the formula $E[g(X)] = \sum_x g(x) p(x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E(X^k)$ is the k-th moment of the random variable X.

It is defined as $E(X^k)=\sum x_i^k\cdot f(x_i)=\sum x_i^k\cdot p_i$

For $k=1$ you get the expectation value: $E(X)=\sum x_i\cdot p_i$

For $k=2$ you get $E(X^2)=\sum x_i^2\cdot p_i$

Thus the definition of the second moment has been used.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the formula $E[f(X)]=\sum_xf(x)p(x)$. We have
$$\text{Var}(X)=E[(X-\mu)^2]=E[X^2]-2\mu E[X]+\mu^2.$$
Then since $E[X^2]=\sum_xx^2p(x)$ and  $\mu=E[X]=\sum_xxp(x)$, everything follows.

Answer (score 0):

$\mu\equiv E([X])$ here. The mean ($\mu$) is the expectation of $X$.